# Issue with using switch in Java

Tags: java, logic, switch-statement

I can't figure out why it's always returning the value of arg1. I'm building a weight converter.

```
public double convert(double arg1,int arg2,int arg3) {
    // arg1 = amount, arg2 = from, arg3 = to
    double milligram = 1;
    double gram = 1000;
    double ounce = 28349.5;
    double pound = 453592;
    double answer = 0;
    switch(arg2) {
    case 0: switch(arg3) { // if milligram
            case 0: answer = (arg1 * milligram) / milligram;
            case 1: answer = (arg1 * milligram) / gram;
            case 2: answer = (arg1 * milligram) / ounce;
            case 3: answer = (arg1 * milligram) / pound;
    }
    case 1: switch(arg3) { // if gram
            case 0: answer = (arg1 * gram) / milligram;
            case 1: answer = (arg1 * gram) / gram;
            case 2: answer = (arg1 * gram) / ounce;
            case 3: answer = (arg1 * gram) / pound;
    }
    case 2: switch(arg3) { // if ounce
            case 0: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / milligram;
            case 1: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / gram;
            case 2: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / ounce;
            case 3: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / pound;
    }
    case 3: switch(arg3) { // if pound
            case 0: answer = (arg1 * pound) / milligram;
            case 1: answer = (arg1 * pound) / gram;
            case 2: answer = (arg1 * pound) / ounce;
            case 3: answer = (arg1 * pound) / pound;
    }
    } // end arg2 switch
    return answer;
}
```

I messed up somewhere in my logic, but I'm failing to see where.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just name your arguments amount, from and to?

Comment: In this case, it would be better to use arrays and remove the switches altogether. Something like `answer = (arg1 * conv[arg2]) / conv[arg3];`

Comment: @irrelephant I prefer to use switch statements as they're easier for me to understand. I haven't used them in a long time so I completely forgot about having to break each case.

Comment: I only suggest it since you'd be able to reduce the code from about 30 lines to 2 :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `break` statements:

```
case 0: 
   answer = (arg1 * milligram) / milligram;
   break;
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

rewrite  every case like this

```
case 2: switch(arg3) { // if ounce
        case 0: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / milligram;break;
        case 1: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / gram;break;
        case 2: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / ounce;break;
        case 3: answer = (arg1 * ounce) / pound;break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested case statements are pretty hard to read, and tough to debug.  It'd be a better idea to encapsulate the functionality you need into a method call instead.

That being said, there's no `break` statement anywhere in your switch.  Regardless of the case, it will fall through to the last case (setting answer equal to the bottom of the case).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `break` in switch statements,else your result may get detoriated

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `break`, using `return` statements does the trick as well as it also prevents falling through cases.

```
case 2: switch(arg3) { // if ounce
    case 0: return (arg1 * milligram) / milligram;
```